# Print TTY Stream to Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, driver, uart, tty

I have a usb device. The driver for said device (a generic USB to UART driver for that chipset) sets up a ttyUSB0 stream for interfacing with the device. I am trying to understand how the data from this device is formatted. Is it possible to display that stream, live, on my terminal (something like piping to stdout)?

This device is running on a limited embedded system. The system uses a Linux 2.6 kernel and busybox shell, so I can't simply install applications like a serial terminal, and many cli programs which are default on most distros (such as screen) aren't available on my system.

Comment: i read the "tour" page to see if this is on-topic. i think this falls under the topic for "questions about software development tools", which are considered on-topic.

Comment: I think you might try tailing it as a binary file:
"tail -c +1 -f **file_name** "

Comment: Simply type `busybox` to get a list of available commands.  Look for a `hexdump` command.  Otherwise consider writing & installing a similar program for your embedded system.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cat`.

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If it's not setup correctly, do it with `stty`. For example to set baud rate:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```